# Pass value to report viewer

Tags: asp.net, report

I am having a aspx file that consist of a reportviewer. The report I am having is not table but its consist of few textbo(which require some value from previous aspx). How can I pass these value into the report viewer?

image below is design of the report.
[image]

I am using rdlc to create the report.
I do create a textbox name as para01.
just wonder how can I do it from C# code to pass into report viewer.
I am using VS2014 web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have very few values you can use query strings to pass them to your `ReportViewer` page; i.e.:

```
Me.Response.Redirect("~/yourFolder/yourReportViewerPage.aspx?" _
    & "staffname=" & txtStaffName.Text & "&" _
    & "taskName=" & txtTaskName.Text)
```

Then convert every value in a `ReportParameter` in your `ReportViewer` page (I usually use `Page_Load` event):

```
Dim parStaffName As New ReportParameter("parStaffName", Me.Request.QueryString("staffName"))
Dim parTaskName As New ReportParameter("parTaskName", Me.Request.QueryString("taskName"))

yourReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {parStaffName, parTaskName})
```

Define these parameters in your report and read them using:

```
=Parameters!parStaffName.Value
```

This is the C# code; hope it works!

Query strings:

```
Response.Redirect("~/yourFolder/yourReportViewerPage.aspx?staffname=" + txtStaffName.Text + "&taskName=" + txtTaskName.Text);
```

Report parameters:

```
ReportParameter parStaffName = new ReportParameter("parStaffName", Request.QueryString("staffName"));
ReportParameter parTaskName = new ReportParameter("parTaskName", Request.QueryString("taskName"));
yourReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {parStaffName, parTaskName});
```

Comment: I am looking for C# not vb... but thanks for your comment :)